# How to enable logging and tracing for AWS API GW via Swagger (or template)

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, swagger, aws-api-gateway, sam

I have an AWS SAM template and I referenced a Swagger file as API configs.
I'm trying to enable logging and tracing for this API. Couldn't find a resource that has this configs. Not sure also if these `enabling logs and tracing` is a thing in the template or in Swagger file.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the **MethodSettings** property under api gateway can help you out

```html
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      MethodSettings:
      - LoggingLevel: ERROR # ERROR/INFO level logging 
        ResourcePath: '/*' # allows for logging on any resource
        HttpMethod: '*' # allows for logging on any method
        DataTraceEnabled: true # enabling Log full requests/responses data in console
        MetricsEnabled: true    # Enable detailed metrics (error 404, latence, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there isn't an option to enable logs via Swagger. Swagger just lets you define the structure of a REST API - resources, integrations, mappings etc. Also, Swagger can be used for defining any REST API; not just Amazon API Gateway. So, it makes sense that you have option to enable logs on a property that's specific to API Gateway - which is a [Stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-stages.html).

If you are creating your API via CloudFormation or some other automated way, you would need to create a deployment for your API. Once you associate this deployment to a API Gateway stage, you can configure settings for logging on it. For example with CloudFormation, you would use `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment StageDescription`. Check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-stagedescription.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using AWS SAM, which converts SAM template to CF template after packaging the project. I'll check how to add this part to it.

Comment: I managed to do this part, but it only passes the custom access logging. Will try to get the CloudWatch logs also.